import.meta.url emits file:/// rather than http://?
I've read the docs of import.meta.url saying :

The full URL to the module, includes query parameters and/or hash
(following the ? or #). In browsers, this is either the URL from which
the script was obtained (for external scripts), or the URL of the
containing document (for inline scripts). In Node.js, this is the file
path (including the file:// protocol).

I created a simple React app with this code:
console.log(import.meta.url); //here
export function App() {
  ...
  ...
  console.log(import.meta.url); //also here
  ...

Then I created assets (js, css, html) via npm run build (webpack etc.) and deployed them in an Nginx Docker container.
However, when I run the code, I get this:

Question:
Why do I see file:// instead of http://? It's not in node mode, and it is a module (App.tsx) is a module .

What does webpack do (I know what bundeling is) that it still fetches chunks of js and still those chunks show file:/// when they are lazy fetched ?


If you bundled the module, file:/// is correct – and there may be no corresponding http:// URL anyway. Do you need that module bundled to a separate file for dynamic import or something? How are you going to use the URL?

@Ry- I don't understand. the index.html file , does load the script file as a regular script. so why a file:// ?? Can you give me a test case where if i change in my simple project ,i will see http ?

Modern JavaScript typically has a build step where modules are resolved at build time and bundled into one or more scripts, so the script the browser loads doesn’t correspond to exactly one input module and may not be a <script type="module"> at all. In your case, some kind of build step is mandatory, since you have (the potential for) TypeScript and JSX, which the browser doesn’t understand. Re: test: I don’t want to spend time figuring out a patch for this starter’s React+TypeScript build process unless it solves a problem you actually have, …

… but you can use <script type="module">import … from "/foo.js";</script> + console.log(import.meta.url) in plain JavaScript in a plain HTML file to see native ES modules in practice.

@Ry-f This question comes from this scenario : I have website a.com which fetches (microfrontend) another site b.com and that b.com site needs to doesnload its own configs (from his(!) nginx). but he doesn't know what the nginx address. ( sure we solved it by param way) . but i was wondering : if a component on b.com is running ,  and i put there import.meta.url , b.com will be able to KNOW that its url is b.com. that's the scenario

By default Webpack will replace the value of import.meta.url with the module's file: URL at build time. You haven't stated what version of Webpack you are using, but support for allowing dynamic import.meta.url values was added in versions >= 5.68.0 via PR 15246 as a result of issue 14445.
To disable Webpack replacing import.meta.url at build time with the module's associated file: URL update your configuration:
module: {
  parser: {
    javascript: {
      importMeta: false,
    },
  },
},

Here is the documentation for enabling or disabling evaluation of import.meta at build time.
You can see an example of a build configuration that uses this and returns the value of import.meta.url you want: https://github.com/morganney/import-meta. This is also hosted on GitHub pages at https://morganney.github.io/import-meta/

Why?

This is a design question, and as such you're better off asking the designers, however, I'll offer a possible reason.
Webpack supports different targets. One of those is node and  Node.js supports CommonJS and ES Modules. There is no equivalent of import.meta.url in CommonJS which was supported before  ES modules and that may be why it is rewritten during the build by default, because you may be targeting a CJS environment. Moreover, you may be targeting web where some browsers do not support native ES modules.
Other bundlers like rollup and swc have had to go through a similar process of how to deal with import.meta.url in various contexts. Thus, there are configuration options to tell Webpack how to handle import.meta.url during a build. Having an explicit option for this, rather than trying to infer it all from your target and/or browserslist file was probably a more reliable way to proceed with easier to maintain code, but you should ask the maintainers for a more definitive reason "why" they chose this design.

What does webpack do that it still fetches chunks of js and still those chunks show file:/// when they are lazy fetched?

It is the Webpack source code on GitHub. Referenced from the issue I mentioned above. Within lib/dependencies/importMetaPlugin.js: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/dependencies/ImportMetaPlugin.js#L99

webpackversion ( in node_modules ) :   "version": "5.90.0",

Question is : why do  -  "By default Webpack will replace the value of import.meta.url with the module's file:" ? i mean if i have 5 chunks being loaded dynamically and at each chunks there are modules with console.log(import.meta.url) , then why is it showing it as a file://? essentially there IS an HTTP request. so i don't understand really what's going on here and why

I've added an example on GitHub: https://morganney.github.io/import-meta/
